# Display Errors For Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a nested form in my view;

```
<%= simple_form_for @form, url: url do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :name %>

  <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>

  <%= f.fields_for :account, { :class => 'field' } do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.collection_radio_buttons(:account_type_id, AccountType.all, :id, :name, selected: ff.object.account_type_id) { |b| radio_button_builder(b) } %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my Form object (extending Reform);

```
class ProgrammeForm < ApplicationForm
  properties :name, :description, validates: {presence: true}

  property :account do
    property :account_type_id
    validates :account_type_id, presence: true
  end
end
```

If I submit the form without filling in any fields, then my `<% if @form.errors.any? %>` partial will print out three errors;

```
3 Errors prohibited this from being saved:
Name can't be blank
Description can't be blank
Account account type can't be blank
```

But there is no "error-looking" HTML on my nested form (the account_type stuff). Name and description are fine (as those are fairly straight forward). But;

1. `fields_for` doesn't put a div wrapper around the radio buttons collection to begin with.
2. There is no other indication that there was an error on this field (like with name and description).

How can I address these two points?

Comment: if you use `simple_form` (as the code suggests) then it also has `simple_fields_for` which might be the answer to your troubles

Comment: doesn't seem to be doing the trick. would it have anything to do with the lack of a div being available around all the check-boxes? i can imagine that being a problem.

Comment: Did you also use the `simple_form` input helpers inside `simple_fields_for`? They should wrap the necessary tags around the input by default